# How to show different font size for values depending on key in one row for wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, font-size

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
var output = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(){
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("integer", "value2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string", "value3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("decimal", "value4"),
};
```

I need to show keys and value in one row, and values of integer and decimal should have bigger font and be bold.

it should be shown like this:

> [string:value1],[integer:**value2**],[string:value3],[decimal:**value4**]

Comment: You might want to look into TextBlock and Run. You could use that to split the content and use different font weights.

Comment: You could use a `IValueConverter` to convert your `string` (string, integer, decimal, ...) into `FontWeight` (e.g. `Bold`).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest and recommended way is to use a `ListView` where the `ListView.ItemsPanel` is a `StackPanel` with a horizontal orientation. To align the items and to remove the selection behavior a `Style`is assigned to the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` that disables hit testing for the items an removes the padding.
A `ListView.ItemTemplate` is used to layout the `ListViewItem`.

This approach is XAML only and offers the best flexibility when it comes to layout styling and behavior.

**View model**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Entries = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
    {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string", "value1"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("integer", "value2"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string", "value3"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("decimal", "value4"),
    };
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion

  private ObservableCollection<string> entries;
  public ObservableCollection<string> Entries
  {
    get => this.entries;
    set
    {
      this.entries = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">

      <!-- Make the items align horizontally -->
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>

      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
          <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

      <!-- Layout the item -->
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>             
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="SeparatorTextBlock" Text="," />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, StringFormat=[{0}]:}" />
            <TextBlock Text="[" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ValueTextBlock"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="]" />
          </StackPanel>

          <DataTemplate.Triggers>

            <!-- Set the FontWeight of the "ValueTextBlock" from bold to normal, if the Key has the value 'string' -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key}" Value="string">
              <Setter TargetName="ValueTextBlock" Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <!-- Remove the leading comma when the item is the first in the collection -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter TargetName="SeparatorTextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Alternatively you can use a `ContentPresenter` as a placeholder and bind `ContentPresenter.Content` to `Entries` using a `EntryToTextBlockConverter` `IValueConverter`. Layout adjustments must be done in C# and is therefore less convenient:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>), typeof(TextBlock))]
public class EntriesToTextBlockConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var result = string.Empty;
    if (value is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> entries)
    {
      var inlines = new List<Inline>();
      entries.ToList().ForEach(
        entry =>
        {
          inlines.Add(new Run("[" + entry.Key + "]:"));
          if (entry.Key.Equals("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            inlines.Add(new Run("[" + entry.Value + "]"));
          else
          {
            inlines.Add(new Run("["));
            inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("[" + entry.Value + "]")));
            inlines.Add(new Run("]"));
          }
          inlines.Add(new Run(","));
        });

      inlines.RemoveAt(inlines.Count - 1);
      var textBlock = new TextBlock();
      textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
      return textBlock;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Ressources>
    <local:EntriesToTextBlockConverter x:Key="EntriesToTextBlockConverter" />
  </Window.Ressources>

  <Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Entries, Converter={StaticResource EntriesToTextBlockConverter}}">
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all in C# and using one `TextBlock`. Try this -

Create a function -

```
    private List<Run> GetRunItem(KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue, bool addComma)
    {
        var inlines = new List<Run>();
        if (keyValue.Key.Equals("string", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            inlines.Add(new Run
            {
                Text = $"[{keyValue.Key}:{keyValue.Value}]{(addComma ? "," : "")}"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            inlines.Add(new Run
            {
                Text = $"[{keyValue.Key}:"
            });
            inlines.Add(new Run
            {
                Text = $"{keyValue.Value}",
                FontSize = 18,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
            });
            inlines.Add(new Run
            {
                Text = $"]{(addComma ? "," : "")}"
            });
        }
        return inlines;
    }
```

And call it like -

```
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
        {
            var runItems = GetRunItem(output[i], i < output.Count - 1);
            textBlock.Inlines.AddRange(runItems);
        }
```